# Why include abstract classes in the java language?

Tags: java, abstract-class, abstract

It seems that every program that uses an `abstract class` could be rewritten without any `abstract classes`.

For example,

```
abstract class Animal {
  abstract int age();
}

class Dog extends Animal {
  @Override int age() { return ... }
}

class Cat extends Animal {
  @Override int age() { return ... }
}
```

If I have to implement `age` in the Dog and Cat classes, why define it `abstract` in the base class instead of providing a placeholder implementation:

```
class Animal {
  int age() { throw new Error("override me"); }
}
```

Are there any real world examples that show why `abstract class` is part of the language? Provide some examples to illustrate the concept.

Comment: Because you can enforce that the abstract method is in fact *present*

Comment: *"If we can do aur job without using abstract classes then why do we even need them?"* - If we can program a computer by using a logic board and a soldering iron, why do we need software?

Comment: You can write methods taking `Animal`s as arguments, and then pass it `Cat`s and `Dog`s without needing to modify anything. You add a level of **type-safety** which makes your programs easier to reason about, debug, and extend.

Comment: @hnefatl this you can do with inheritance. You don't need abstract classes for this.

Comment: @David Well 10GB of "software" made from solder would be really heavy.  The soft stuff weighs less.

Comment: @Turing85 You can, but it sounds like OP's actually confused about why we'd use superclasses/interfaces in general - "*what is the need for it to be in base class?*"

Comment: the job can be done without many things, but would it make it easier?

Comment: @hnefatl "what is the need for it to be in base class?**" - "it": "the abstract method". OP seems to acknowledge the usefulness of inheritance. And interfaces is not part of the discussion.

Comment: Because using the `abstract` keyword shows you really know your Java-fu.

Comment: This is a similar question where you'll find arguments for and against abstract classes. In my Java experience, I can't recall ever needing them. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/94887/are-abstract-classes-methods-obsolete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any class that can be instantiated should meet its contract so that all values meet their type contracts.

For example

```
Animal a = new Animal();  // Would compile if Animal not abstract.
System.err.println(a.age());  // Use of a value that may not meet its contract.
```

If `Animal` is `abstract` then this would produce a useful, compile-time error that tells the user that they need to instantiate a specific `Animal` subtype.

Abstract classes provide a way to define an interface without providing a complete implementation that meets a contract while providing a clear signal to those who are looking to construct an instance.

They provide a structure around which a full implementation can be fleshed out letting the author delegate the responsibility to complete the contract to authors of subtypes.

Answer (score 1):

We don't *need* abstract classes, but they are useful in some cases (though sometimes overused - often interfaces are more appropriate in my opinion).

Your example with `age()` may not be the best one because calculating the age of a dog and the age of a cat will probably be the same, i.e. current date minus date of birth.

But consider this example: Say you have another abstract method `move(destination)` in your class `Animal`. Then the `Fish` class may implement this method by swimming, the `Dog` class by walking, the `Frog` class by jumping and the `Bird` class by flying.

So if you have a list of `Animal` objects, you *know* they all are able to move, but it does not matter to the caller *how* a specific animal moves.

Comment: if they might be useful, then we *do need* them :)

Comment: @Andrew: Well, you don't *need* a fork to eat spaghetti (i.e. you can also use your fingers alone), but it is still *useful* to use a fork to avoid burning your fingers and getting them dirty... ;-)